# Get a sprite to follow/chase another in Livewires python?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, livewires

I am trying to make a top down shooter style game and am having a hard time getting a sprite to "chase" the player's sprite.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a code fragment that you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **seek** behavior will work for chasing. http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/understanding-steering-behaviors-seek/

If you don't want that, you can use vectors to get the direction from one unit to the other. ( Then scale the length / cap it )